# Is there an equivalent to SQL_NO_CACHE in MongoDB?

Tags: performance, mongodb, profiling

I'm looking for the best way to compare query run times in MongoDB (using `.explain()`), but have noticed drastic differences in `millis` between subsequent runs of the same query.

In MySQL, [SQL_NO_CACHE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-in-select.html) would help.

Comment: you would then be measuring how long it takes to fetch data from disk, rather than how long it takes to evaluate the query, etc.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky OK - how can you do this in a way to easily compare how fast different queries take in fetching data from disk?

Comment: that's not related to DB or queries - you want to simulate real conditions if you're benchmarking your application.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky sorry I think I misread your first comment. so what's the best way to benchmark different queries in the actual production env? Running multiple times gives wildly different times.

Comment: It shouldn't give wildly different times except for first time vs. subsequent times.  I would throw away the first time and compare the subsequent times - since you would be aiming for the data being in cache, you would then be comparing apples to apples.  If in real world your data is frequently not in cache, I would look into whether you need more RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Why not taking the opposite approach, which is to compare performance *with* the data in the cache? That is more representative of what you will try to do in production.

In order to 'warm your data', you can use the 'touch' command, which will load the data and indexes in memory.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/touch/